# "Build out" meaning

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

While reading "The Educated Imagination" I got confused with the meaning of the following sentence:

> So you soon realize that there's a difference between the world you are living in and the world you want to live in. The world you want to live in is a human world, not an objective one: it's not an environment but a home; **it's not the world you see but the world you build out of what you see**. You go to work to build a shelter or plant a garden ...

The meaning would be that you don't want to live in the world you see but in the world that you built to be what you want to see?

Comment: "Build out of" is a synonym of "build from" or "build using".